# nginx trailing slash issues

Tags: configuration, nginx

I'm googling a lot and found several workarounds, but you have to define every single directory.

- On Apache: example.com/hi -> example.com/hi/
- On nginx: example.com/hi -> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at example.com:8888

where 8888 is what Apache is listening on (nginx's :80 -> localhost:8888)

Any ideas how to fix this and have it just forward normally like folder?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with varnish and nginx (varnish on port 80 proxying to nginx listening on 8080) and needed to add "port_in_redirect off;"  ... server_name_in_redirect needed to stay on so nginx knew which host it was handling.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick, but it needs more thought/work, because only a single location block will get used at a time:

```
location ~ ^(.*[^/])$ {
  if (-d $document_root/$1) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1/ permanent;
  }
}
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 1):

You can set "server_name_in_redirect off" on your server section

```
server{
  listen 80 default;
  server_name localhost;
  server_name_in_redirect off;

 ...
 ...
}
```

That will do the trick ;-)

HTH.

Edit: Just format.

Comment: This fixed a redirect problem for me. +1!

Answer (score 0):

This is the magic that works best for me:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect;
location @redirect {
    if ($uri !~ '/$') {
        return 301 $uri/$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

The 'if' statement here is safe per: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil